# PTIJ: Did the people mean what we think they meant?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Torah says:

> וַיִּקַּח֙ סֵ֣פֶר הַבְּרִ֔ית וַיִּקְרָ֖א בְּאׇזְנֵ֣י הָעָ֑ם וַיֹּ֣אמְר֔וּ כֹּ֛ל אֲשֶׁר־דִּבֶּ֥ר יְהֹוָ֖ה נַעֲשֶׂ֥ה וְנִשְׁמָֽע׃

> Then [Moses] took the book of the covenant and read it **into the ears** of the people. And they said, “All that God has spoken we will do and we will hear!”  [Ex. 24:7]

Much has been written about the inspirational response of the people.  But did a commentator ever suggest they really meant: "Will you please stop blaring in our ears?"

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I'm not sure why this qualifies as Purim Torah. The suggestion that they agreed quickly to so-to-speak shut him up seems plausible enough to be worth exploring.